# Initramfs - /dev/mapper/vgubuntu cannot does noot exist

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

i updated my Ubuntu today, but during restart there was a boot failure and i ended up at a black screen. There was only a minimal shell for initramfs and when i exited it sayed "vgubuntu-root does not exist. I tried the proposed solution below from usb installation disk and from a previous kernel.Nothing worked. Because there were no useful proposals in french or German.
so i looked up some here, which seemed about related bugs, however none of them has worked so far.

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell! 

BusyBox v.1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.1-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)   
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.  

(initramfs)
```

**the output for <parted -l> is**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   1305MB  768MB   ext4
 3      1305MB  2000GB  1999GB


Model: ATA SanDisk SSD U100 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16,0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   16,0GB  15,5GB  ext4
```

I have done the following so far

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 sda3_crypt
vgchange -ay
mount /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot               #Also tried Sda2 here 
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys/

chroot /mnt
apt install lvm2 cryptsetup-initramfs
update-initramfs -c -k all
```

thus far all of this couldnt fix the failure

I would be very grateful for a  solution 
Thanks in advance

https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/recovering-from-unbootable-ubuntu-encrypted-lvm-root-partition/